# php insert into sql by column number instead of name

Tags: php, sql, insert

Is it possible to do an insert or any other operation based on the column number rather than it's name?
I can't find any documentation, but I wonder if that's just because I'm asking the question the wrong way.

something like :

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO vocabList (1, 2, 3) VALUES ('$one', '$two', '$three')");
```

which is a modified version of :

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO vocabList (rowOne, rowTwo, rowThree) VALUES ('$one', '$two', '$three')");
```

which was working.

Comment: No, but you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to construct such a query.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?